# Change Azure Website platform from 32 to 64 bit with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

A website created with azure powershell defaults to 32bit platform

```
$prop = @{ "serverFarmId" = $plan.Id ; 'Sku' = 'Standard' }
New-AzureResource -ResourceName $webSiteName -Location $plan.Location -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -PropertyObject $prop -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Force }
```

I need to change it to 64bit. I think I can pass some parameter in the PropertyObject via `New-AzureResource` or `Set-AzureResource`, but I can't find the syntax.

**How can I switch my website from 32 to 64 bit (or vice-versa)**

I use the last version of Azure cmdLets to date (July 2015)

**Bonus question :**

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654578.aspx) is not explicit at all about possible values:

> -PropertyObject Specifies the new property values. Enter a hash table of property names and values. The names and values are
>   case-sensitive.

Where can we found more info about these cmdLets? (yes, I tried google...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change your running website from 32-bit to 64-bit, you can use the following PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Get-AzureWebsite "websitenamegoeshere"
```

Look at the Use32BitWorkerProcess value...this would allow you to look at the properties of the website to confirm the 32-bit process.

To change this value to false (and thus 64-bit) use the following:

```
Set-AzureWebsite "websitenamegoeshere" -Use32BitWorkerProcess $false
```

If you re-run the Get-AzureWebsite command, you should be able to confirm the value is now false. Additionally, if you check your website properties in the Azure portal, you should be able to confirm that it is now configured for 64-bit.

**NOTE: You might need to refresh the browser with an F5 for cached values to be reloaded.**

Comment: So simple. I just found the solution with Resource Manager mode, I was about to post it.

Answer (score 2):

@Brian's solution works, but this one worked too.
It has the advantage in my case of setting "AlwaysOn", `Set-AzureWebsite` does not have this parameter.

```
$r = Get-AzureResource -ResourceName testskuws -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-NorthCentralUS -OutputObjectFormat New
$r.Properties.SiteConfig = @{ 'AlwaysOn' = $true ; 'Use32BitWorkerProcess' = $false }
$r | Set-AzureResource -OutputObjectFormat New
```

With Azure cmdlets version of July 2015